# tmux "chord" keyboard shortcuts not being interpreted on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, key-bindings

I'm trying to use "chord" keyboard shortcuts for tmux (ctrl+b, ctrl+d to detach, ctrl+b, ctrl+[ to scroll), and they are not being interpreted.

What I've tried:

- I tried this in VS Code (remote), VS Code (local) and my local terminal and it didn't work in any of them, so I believe this is a Mac or a tmux issue.
- This seems random - it worked up until a few hours ago and suddenly stopped. I'm thinking I accidentally changed some setting or received some mac update. But I don't recall either of those things happening.
- I tried reinstalling tmux, reinstalling vs code, updating Mac.
- The VS Code terminal.integrated.allowChords setting is set to "True"
- My cursor disappears after the "ctrl+b" step when the terminal is focused. If I try doing this command when, e.g. a browser window is focused, the cursor does not disappear.
- If I use this in a normal terminal (outside tmux), ctrl+b does nothing, then ctrl+d deletes a character. But inside tmux, ctrl+b does nothing, then ctrl+d also does nothing. So it seems like the command is getting captured somehow.

Other chord commands work (e.g. cmd+shift+t to open recently closed tab).

What might be causing this issue?

Comment: please post your tmux conf.

Comment: I have no tmux conf, it is a fresh tmux install

Comment: aha. just googled and found what "chord" means here: https://forums.ultraedit.com/what-is-meant-by-a-chord-in-context-of-key-mapping-t17210.html

Comment: so how can you try it in your "local terminal"? i don't think it should work with default tmux conf.

Comment: By local terminal I meant not in VS Code but inside the Mac terminal, and locally as in a local tmux installation, not ssh-ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the full tmux settings to ~/.tmux.conf as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294956/how-do-i-get-a-default-tmux-configuration-file) solved this:

```
tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf
```